How can I set escape character for GNU Screen, when created
Somehow, setting the escape character when creating a new screen, does not work.
screen -e "^Bb"

This does however work, if I attach to an existing screen.
screen -dr -e "^Bb"

, so it's only when creating a new screen I get this problem
